# tableview won't load on iPhone but loads on simulator what's wrong?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

i have an app with two buttons. On startup the first screen is a web view and that works fine, but when i tap a button a table view should show up but it is blank. Th table view data is loaded from a plist i created as a file. Everything show up in the simulator. I have Xcode 4.2. My device is the iPhone 4s. Any answer on what this might be, please help! Thank you.

Comment: Are there any errors? Could be that your xml file is not getting created or written when running on the device.  Can you verify that your data is actually being read by the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful: the simulator uses Mac OSX's File access, which is case-insensitive. Running on the device, the file access is case sensetive. Did you check your cases?